# Getting error "Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:3564879), database ID 7." But a database with Id 7 DOES NOT exist

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, dbcc-checkdb

I have a testing environment where I have scheduled jobs running restore tests as well as DBCC checks. These jobs run to:
1) copy database back up from the prod.
2) `DROP` all existing databases except `dba_utility`
3) restore the backup
4) run `dbcc checkdb`

I frequently get:

```
Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:3564879), database ID 7.
```

The weird thing is, there is no database with an `Id` of `7`.
`Maximum Id` in `sys.databases` catalog view is 6. (Remember, the job `DROP` all databases before the restore operation except `dba_utility` whose `Id=5`. The newly restored database is assigned the Id of 6.)

Prod environment is 2008 R2, test environment is 2012 SP1.

What might be causing this?

Comment: Please make sure both SQL Server versions are patched to [Latest Service pack](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved after enabling Instant File Initialization

Answer (score 5):

> run dbcc checkdb

CHECKDB [creates a database snapshot behind the scenes](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/issues-around-dbcc-checkdb-and-the-use-of-hidden-database-snapshots/). This is your DBID 7.

As for the timeout, perhaps [KB919155 Error message when you run the DBCC CHECKDB statement on a database that contains one or more very large tables in SQL Server: "Timeout occurred while waiting for latch"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919155). "This behavior is by design.". Is page 3564879 an [IAM chain page](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-iam-pages-iam-chains-and-allocation-units/)?

Comment: Thanks. +1 for db snapshot Id.
How can I know if page 3564879 is an IAM chain page?

Comment: See the link in the response *we can see that there’s an IAM page: a page with type 10*

Comment: No. It is not a IAM chain page. It is m_type = 16 which corresponds to [diff map page.](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/)

Comment: Best avenue is to contact [CSS](http://support.microsoft.com)

Comment: If I change the recovery model of the db to 'Simple' and run checkdb again, I get the same error message but this time for a different page (1:3944) which is of type 2 (index page).

Comment: From the KB919155:"...The tables are typically several hundred gigabytes (GB) in size..." Total database size is ~135 GB.