# DBCC CHECKDB on a user database: Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (X:XXX), database ID 2

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, dbcc-checkdb, timeout, latch

Our Ola Hallengren IntegrityCheck job failed due to a buffer latch timeout while running DBCC CHECKDB on a user database.

However, the buffer latch timeout reported was in TempDB (database ID 2).

Output from the job:

```
Date and time: 2022-01-22 09:04:15 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Database context: [master] [SQLSTATE 01000]
Command: SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 600000; DBCC CHECKDB ([SentryOne]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, MAXDOP = 4 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 845, Sev 17, State 1, Line 1 : Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (6:222), database ID 2. [SQLSTATE 42000]
Outcome: Failed [SQLSTATE 01000]
Duration: 12:40:32 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Date and time: 2022-01-22 21:44:47 [SQLSTATE 01000]
```

Messages in the SQL Error Log:

```
Date 1/22/2022 9:35:22 PM
Log SQL Server (Archive #1 - 1/23/2022 12:00:00 AM)

Source spid777

Message
A time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch -- type 2, bp 0000016D7A1DE340, page 6:222, stat 0x40d, database id: 2, allocation unit Id: 536870912/281475513581568, task 0x0000016CD624E4E8 : 2, waittime 300 seconds, flags 0x1a, owning task 0x0000016CD624E4E8. Not continuing to wait.

BobMgr::GetBuf: Sort Big Output Buffer write not complete after 60 seconds.

DBCC CHECKDB (SentryOne) WITH all_errormsgs, no_infomsgs, maxdop = 4 executed by NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT terminated abnormally due to error state 6. Elapsed time: 12 hours 39 minutes 57 seconds.

[INFO] Database ID: [12]. Cleaning up StorageArray. LastClosedCheckpointEndTs: '1225176490'

[WARNING] ALTER or DROP TABLE could not clean up root row within 10 seconds.
```

The page in question is an IAM page in TempDB. DBCC PAGE output for it:

```
PAGE: (6:222)

BUFFER:

BUF @0x0000016D6B622C40

bpage = 0x00000161A6C52000 bPmmpage = 0x0000000000000000 bsort_r_nextbP = 0x0000016D6B622AD0
bsort_r_prevbP = 0x0000016D6B622B80 bhash = 0x0000000000000000 bpageno = (6:222)
bpart = 4 ckptGen = 0x0000000000000000 bDirtyRefCount = 0
bstat = 0x9 breferences = 3 berrcode = 0
bUse1 = 19321 bstat2 = 0x0 blog = 0x215a215a
bsampleCount = 1 bIoCount = 0 resPoolId = 0
bcputicks = 330 bReadMicroSec = 848 bDirtyContext = 0x0000000000000000
bDbPageBroker = 0x0000000000000000 bdbid = 2 bpru = 0x0000016D3A170040

PAGE HEADER:

Page @0x00000161A6C52000

m_pageId = (6:222) m_headerVersion = 1 m_type = 10
m_typeFlagBits = 0x0 m_level = 0 m_flagBits = 0x200
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 1837007664 m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 28675
Metadata: AllocUnitId = 8071415347312328704
Metadata: PartitionId = 2162691495132069888 Metadata: IndexId = 0
Metadata: ObjectId = -1083263203 m_prevPage = (0:0) m_nextPage = (0:0)
pminlen = 90 m_slotCnt = 2 m_freeCnt = 6
m_freeData = 8182 m_reservedCnt = 0 m_lsn = (324:1435184:42)
m_xactReserved = 0 m_xdesId = (0:0) m_ghostRecCnt = 0
m_tornBits = -551517712 DB Frag ID = 1

Allocation Status

GAM (6:2) = ALLOCATED SGAM (6:3) = ALLOCATED
PFS (6:1) = 0x70 IAM_PG MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED 0_PCT_FULL DIFF (6:6) = NOT CHANGED
ML (6:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED

IAM: Header @0x00000036C4278064 Slot 0, Offset 96

sequenceNumber = 0 status = 0x0 objectId = 0
indexId = 0 page_count = 0 start_pg = (8:511232)

IAM: Single Page Allocations @0x00000036C427808E

Slot 0 = (0:0) Slot 1 = (0:0) Slot 2 = (0:0)
Slot 3 = (0:0) Slot 4 = (0:0) Slot 5 = (0:0)
Slot 6 = (0:0) Slot 7 = (0:0)

IAM: Extent Alloc Status Slot 1 @0x00000036C42780C2

(8:511232) - (8:592656) = NOT ALLOCATED
(8:592664) - = ALLOCATED
(8:592672) - (8:770424) = NOT ALLOCATED
```

I found this DBA StackExchange question which seems to be most closely relevant:
[Getting error "Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:3564879), database ID 7." But a database with Id 7 DOES NOT exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/getting-error-time-out-occurred-while-waiting-for-buffer-latch-type-2-for-page)

However, in that scenario, the timed-out page reported is in a user database and not TempDB.

Also, we're on the latest SQL Server version (2019-CU14 Enterprise) so this should not be happening anyway.

I did notice that there was very high latency on TempDB data files around 6 PM and 9:40 PM.
I'm unsure whether it's related, though, because the latency spike at 6 PM is higher and yet the job failed only around 9:44 PM.

[image: TempDB Data Files Latency]

These latency spikes do not correlate with any spikes in the Azure Monitor metrics `VM Cached IOPS Consumed Percentage` and `VM Cached Bandwidth Consumed Percentage`.

Additional information:

- The server is installed on an Azure VM: `Standard E8s v3 (8 vcpus, 64 GiB memory)`
- The user database in question (SentryOne) has memory-optimized
  tables.
- TempDB Memory-Optimized metadata is DISABLED.
- Instant File Initialization is ENABLED.
- Lock Pages in Memory is DISABLED.

Any ideas why this happened and how to prevent it in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the buffer latch timeout reported was in TempDB (database ID 2).

TempDB is used with [CheckDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), most likely there was a set of items waiting on the latch (or a single item, can't say with the data provided) and either the there was a convoy occurence due to something being slow (for example, IO or memory allocations) or there was a single occurence of this.

> A time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2, bp 0000016D7A1DE340, page **6**:222, stat **0x40d**, database id: 2, allocation unit Id: 536870912/281475513581568, task 0x0000016CD624E4E8 : 2, **waittime 300 seconds**, flags **0x1a**, owning task 0x0000016CD624E4E8. Not continuing to wait. (Bolding mine, for emphasis)

- page 6:222 - Specifically tempdb fileid 6
- stat 0x40d (buffer) - In IO
- Waittime 300 seconds - Timeout after waiting a *long* time
- flags 0x1a (latch) - In IO, Exclusive Access

> I did notice that there was very high latency on TempDB data files around 6 PM and 9:40 PM. I'm unsure whether it's related, though, because the latency spike at 6 PM is higher and yet the job failed only around 9:44 PM.

According to your screenshot ad the output of the job:

- Date and time: 2022-01-22 09:04:15
- Disk IO taking 300,000+ ms (300+ seconds)

That correlates pretty well, looks to be some slow disk at the time based on the available data.

Comment: I suspected that this was due to disk latency, but I couldn't correlate this with any performance metrics of the VM at Azure Monitor. I'm considering whether to open a support request for Azure about this, but if this is a one-time thing then maybe there's no point. If this happens again then I'll obviously reconsider.

Comment: It could happen at any time if there is massive slowness in disk, memory, cpu, etc.